# PDF file shows only 3 or more checked items

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a Kendo Grid with a column (UniqueId) that can be checked:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  class='primaryBox' id='#= UniqueId #' value='#= UniqueId #'>#= UniqueId #</input>");
```

The checked items have been sent to the ASP.NET MVC Controller (C#) by javascript function:

```
function getChecked() {        

        var ids = new Array();

        $('.primaryBox:checked').map(function (index) {
            ids.push(this.id);
        });        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/PatientReport/ExportToPDF",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { uniqueIds: ids },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {                    
                    $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/PatientReport/DownloadFile' + '?fName=' + data.fName);                   
                } else {                   
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#checkedMsg').text('@ELRegistry.Resources.Views.Patient.PatientStrings.CheckedError').show();

            }
        });
    }
```

In the Controller I have an Action ExportToPDF (using iTextSharp), that put checked UniqueIds to PDF:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ExportToPDF(List<String> uniqueIds)       {

            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 3, 3, 80, 50);            

            //step 2: we create a memory stream that listens to the document
            var output = new MemoryStream();            

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            // calling PDFFooter class to Include in document
            writer.PageEvent = new PDFFooter();

            //step 3: we open the document

            document.Open();            

            // here is the code that puts to the dataTable
            ...

            and then:   

            // Add table to the document
            document.Add(dataTable);

            //This is important don't forget to close the document
            document.Close();



            byte[] byteInfo = output.ToArray();
            output.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
            output.Position = 0;          


            var fName = string.Format("File-{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));
            Session[fName] = output;

            return Json(new { success = true, fName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

and an Action DownloadFile:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fName)
        {
            var ms = Session[fName] as MemoryStream;
            if (ms == null)
                return new EmptyResult();
            Session[fName] = null;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", fName);
        }
```

My problem is in that when I check 1 or 2 UniqueIds, the PDF file doesn't show them (in JavaScript function I see ids, in ExportToPDF Action everything is ok, but the PDF file doesn't show them). If I check 3 or more UniqueIds, everything is fine in the PDF file. Any ideas? How to solve this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: in ExportToPDF where you using uniqueIds?

Comment: In ExportToPDF I use UniqueIds to get a list (with Patients) which have these UniqueIds: ` List<Patient> myList = new Repository().GetPatientsForUniqueIds(uniqueIds);`After that, I work with myList (these data are in PDF file).

Comment: when you give 1 or 2 uniqueids to this method GetPatientsForUniqueIds what you get in the patienList? I believe if you give more than 2 unique ids you get the records appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But in debugger I see myList of corresponding items when I send 1 or 2 UniqueIds. It seems everything is fine, but the PDF is empty.Maybe the output stream is too small ?

Comment: yeah may be try adding some garbage data in output stream when u have uniqueids 1 or 2 & then check the PDF file. what it shows. may be that help you understand problem better.

Comment: that's right, thank you! When I added some garbage data and used UniqueIds 1 or 2, the PDF showed the data!